# Changing a value when a user change a value in the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two identical `DataGridView`, both have the same `Properties`, and same `Events`. But one of them is not changing the value when a user change value inside the `DataGridView`.

This are my `DataGridView` events

```
DataGridView dgvselect;
Label totAmt;
Label totItem;

private void dataGridRight_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabRight.SelectedTab == tabCart)
    {
        dgvselect = dataGridSales;
        totAmt = lblSTotAmt;
        totItem = lblSTotItem;
        dataGridSales.BeginEdit(true);
    }
    if (tabRight.SelectedTab == tabEsti)
    {
        dgvselect = dataGridEsti;
        totAmt = lblETotAmt;
        totItem = lblETotItem;
        dataGridEsti.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}

private void dataGridRight_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int lastqty = Convert.ToInt32(dgvselect.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
    int lessqty = Convert.ToInt32(dgvselect.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    string part = dgvselect.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    int nqty = lastqty - lessqty;
    if (lessqty <= lastqty)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + ip + "," + port + "; Database=records; User ID=" + sqlid + "; Password=" + sqlpass + ""))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [dbo].[products]
            SET Stock = '" + nqty + "' WHERE [Part No.] = '" + part + "'", conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        scrollIndex = dataGridSrch.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        scrollPos = dataGridSrch.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
        searchProd();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            int qty = Convert.ToInt32(dgvselect.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(dgvselect.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
            dgvselect.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = qty * price;
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(dgvselect.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
            dgvselect.Columns[3].ValueType = typeof(Double);
        }
        dgvselect.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH");
        dgvselect.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("C");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exceeds the amount of stock available", "Invalid Purchase", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        dgvselect.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = 1;
    }
}

private void dataGridRight_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabRight.SelectedTab == tabSales || tabRight.SelectedTab == tabEsti)
    {
        int count = 0;
        double total = 0;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvselect.Rows)
            {
                count += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
            }
            totItem.Text = "Total Items: " + count;
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvselect.Rows)
            {
                total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Value);
            }
            totAmt.Text = "Total Amount: " + total.ToString("C2");
        }
        amount = total;
    }
}
```

When the user double clicks the cell, it will start editing and set the `dgvselect`, `totAmt`, and `totItem` values to its corresponding `DataGridView` and `Labels`

But when testing the app, the `Cart` tab page is not firing.

This is the initial values when an item is added inside the `DataGridView`. No changes are made for the `Qty` and `Price`.

[image]

But when there are some changes,

[image]

The `totAmt` and `totItem` texts didn't change. It will only change when an item is added.

[image]

As for the `Estimate` tab page, it can change the text values of `totAmt` and `totItem`.

[image]

[image]

I have tried copying the `DataGridView` in `Estimate` tab page and pasted it in `Cart` tab page.

Comment: what is dataGridRight?

Comment: I have change that event name. Since both of my `DataGridViews` is using that event and they are positioned at the right side. That is not the default event name.

Comment: I have created a separate events for the two `DataGridViews`, if there is a way to shorten just let me know. Why did I have two identical `DataGridView`, because the other one will update my data since ideally it will go straight to payment. The other one will just create an estimate and no payment will be made, so it will not update my data.

Comment: after the changes, the grid is working as you expected?

Comment: @BaskarJohn yes

Comment: seems issue on event subscription. provide the event subscription help to sort out the problem

Comment: @BaskarJohn umm sorry, but what is that? Haha. I'm still new in developing an app.